# Getting full control over content of React.js component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to make React.js component with full control over contents of its dom-element?

Following code creates component `Smth`, which is made from `div` with text passed as text content. It's guaranteed that `text` will be the string.

```js
var Smth = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div(this.props, this.props.text);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Smth, { 
    className: 'some-class',
    style: { color: 'blue' },
    text: "Some text goes here" // Nothing except text is here
  }),
  document.querySelector('main')
);
```

```css
.some-class {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: silver;
  float: left;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.2.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

How can I make following things:

1. React builds and updates div except its content.
2. *The Script* controls the contents of this div and can place text or markup inside of it without any interaction with react model.
3. *The Script* should be informed about changes it the `text` property.
   I expect that this point will be reached by default.

As *The Script* I mean some script written inside of the component, but outside of react control. I need to modify contents of the element independently from react.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464085/178988)

Comment: Could you clarify "some script written inside of the component, but outside of react"? DOM components (e.g. `<DIV>`) are not likely to have scripts, but references to scripts like `<input onChange="myFunction()">`. React components are a different thing, but they are under react control. Javascript (e.g. `document.getElementById("foo")`) can be used to manipulate content. Generally speaking, you really need to choose between A) let ONLY react manipulate DOM, or B) do not use react component, and manipulate DOM directly. In almost all cases, it is a bad idea to mix the two methods.

Comment: @wintvelt, I just need to prevent control over `div`'s child nodes from react side and implement it by myself. And react should inform me when the property changes, so I can refresh contents according to new value. I expect this behavior by default as the component will be recreated and the render method called. But I do need to inform react somehow that it shouldn't update real dom inside of the `div`. It just keeps a string in its virtual dom and never compares it with real dom. I guarantee that it will be a string and that I won't modify neither anything outside `div` nor it's attributes.

Comment: Again: I would strongly advise against directly manipulating child nodes of a react component. Technically it is possible (include a `shouldComponentUpdate()` function that always returns false inside the react child component). If you do not want react to update your DOM (since you do that yourself so react does not know about real DOM anymore), then there is no point in keeping any string in react's virtual DOM. Better to make your own listeners to changes and respond outside react.

Comment: @wintvelt, would it be ok if I create an empty div using `return React.DOM.div(this.props);` and then will add some content into it without informing react?

Comment: @wintvelt, `shouldComponentUpdate: function() { return false; }` seems to be the recommended solution for interaction with external plugins, isn't it?

Comment: Yes (see answer by @KrisCarle) you can have react create an empty div like that. The `shouldComponentUpdate()` is to ensure that react does not re-render the same component, because that could override any changes the other code made to it. (BTW: @KrisCarle answer does not require shouldComponentUpdate, because the added jQuery handler will not be overwritten during re-render).

Comment: @wintvelt, if I create an empty div as I showed above, will I need shouldComponentUpdate false to safely add some content into it?

Comment: Yes, @KrisCarle has been kind enough to update his answer to show how. (would be kind of you to accept his answer ;)

Comment: @wintvelt, why don't you add your own one? Seems like you have a great react experience.

Comment: Thank you. But I think @KrisCarle's answer is better than I would have written..

Comment: @wintvelt, but there is nothing about making it without shouldComponentUpdate. By the way, if I can guarantee that `textContent` property wouldn't change but `innerHTML` would, and I agree react to reset markup in case of `props.text` change, can I safely omit `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: Yes you can omit shouldComponentUpdate if you agree to reset markup (including resetting any innerHTML changes) in case of prop change. Recommend you read also links provided in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to combine React with some non-React code. You can do that by adding a ref to your div, then using `componentDidMount` to get the object once the component mounts. You can then pass that into jQuery etc.

Here is an example from http://taylorlovett.com/2015/08/05/modifying-the-dom-with-jquery-within-react-components-in-isomorphic-applications/ that shows how to use a jQuery tooltip (I've updated it since you are using React 0.14.x above).

I'd also recommend switching to JSX https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html
You won't find many examples of how to do things with the JS calls. I did a quick search and couldn't figure out how to set a ref without JSX, maybe someone else will have more luck...

```
import React from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jQuery';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {         
    jQuery(this.myContent).doSomethingWithjQuery();
    jQuery(this.myContent).bind("DOMSubtreeModified", this.contentUpdated);
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    //tell react not to update
    return false;
  },

 contentUpdated() {
   //do something when external library modifies the dom
 },

  render() {
    <div ref={(el) => { this.myContent = el }">

    </div>
  }
}
```

More about React refs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: How does this code interacts with react? The [official example](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html) also uses `shouldComponentUpdate: function() { return false; }` to prevent rerendering. But your example doesn't. Can you clarify what exactly is allowed because of adding `ref`?

Comment: Simply put: if your code outside react changes any HTML (JSX) code that is inside the render's return statement, then you need `shouldComponentUpdate = false`. The jQuery statement does not change  div's or div's attributes (it only adds handlers). If however, your code change div's text to e.g. "This is YOUR React component". Then you do need the extra shouldComponentUpdate = false.

Comment: In fact, `tooltip` plugin on hover removes `title` attribute and adds `aria-describedby`. When mouse goes out it restores original value. The div with tooltip is placed outside, so there is no changes in this part.

Comment: I updated my example to add shouldComponentUpdate = false, and show a way to catch DOM updates using jQuery

Comment: But I do not want to set shouldComponentUpdate to false as it will stop updating attributes.